# RequireJS shim being ignored in simple example

Tags: javascript, requirejs

As I understand it, you can use a shim with Requirejs to dynamically load scripts that are not defined as modules in their own files. So why can I not get a simple script like this to work?

Here's my non-working example:

**/libs/test.js:**

```
var a = 'Hello from TestJS';
```

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        './libs/test': { exports: 'test'}
    }
}
```

Then trying this in the console:

```
require(['./libs/test'], function(t) { console.log(t); })
```

Which produces `undefined`.

So how do I get hold of `a`?

I can see from the network tab that test.js is loaded from the server. I have a feeling my shim config is being ignored and requirejs is just loading it without the shim. Hence if I just do `console.log(window.a)`, I see 'Hello from TestJS'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code you show for `test.js`, you have to specify that the exported symbol is `a`, not `test` because the latter is never defined in `test.js`:

```
shim: {
    './libs/test': { exports: 'a'}
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this is the simplest explanation of exports I've found. I thought it was something to do with giving the module an ID of some kind.

Comment: My only problem now is how to give this an ID, or a kind of alias, so in my code I can do `require(['myScript'],function(x) { ... })`. I'm trying to use path for this, but then I think it sidesteps my shim.

Comment: Look at the `paths` setting and the `shim` setting for the `bootstrap` module in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21063185/1906307). You need to do the same thing for your script if you want to give it a shorter name: set a `paths` mapping that maps from the short name to the full path (without a `.js` extension) and have the `shim` use the short name too.